# c print char pointer that in main when value changed in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

**main**

```
...
            char coords;
            get_coords(1, &coords);
            printf("{%s}", coords);
...
```

**get_coords:**

```
void get_coords(int num, char *coords){
    if (num == 1){
        *coords = '0-0';
    }
}
```

problem seems to happen when the code tries to execute the printf and simply returns errors back... if i remove that `line of code` or `change` `%s` to `%c` it will work fine...

Comment: `char coords` is a character, not a string of characters. Btw, what's the error message anyway?

Comment: it says `"process returned -1232132131(0xc0000005)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char coords;

printf("{%s}", coords);
```

`coords` is a `char` and not a string. `%s` conversion specification requires a `char *` argument and not a `char`. Passing an object of type `char` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is the format specifier for a C string. You're passing it a simple `char`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably something like this (please add the error checks yourself):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_coords(int num, char *coords)
{
    if (num == 1) {
        coords[0] = '0';
        coords[1] = '-';
        coords[2] = '0';
        coords[3] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char coords[4];
    memset(coords, 0, sizeof(coords));

    get_coords(1, coords);
    printf("{%s}\n", coords);

    return 0;
}
```